# UndoContext of ActiveEditor in Eclipse JDT

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-jdt

I'm building an operation in JDT that extends the classpath of a Java project and adds an import statement to the active Java file. Now I'm having trouble to get the undo operation working. Here is the code that executes the operation and puts it in the undo history:

```
        ExtendClasspathOperation operation = new ExtendClasspathOperation(
                "Update Classpath", document, this.context, this.className,
                this.jarURI);
        IOperationHistory operationHistory = OperationHistoryFactory
                .getOperationHistory();
        IUndoContext undoContext = PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
                .getOperationSupport().getUndoContext();
        operation.addContext(undoContext);
        operationHistory.execute(operation, null, null);
```

What happens is that I can undo "Update Classpath" as long as the current JavaEditor is not focused. Once I focus it, I can only undo "Text Edit". The question now is, what IUndoContext do I have to use? I tried:

```
undoContext = (IUndoContext) this.context.getASTRoot().getJavaElement()
                                .getAdapter(IUndoContext.class);
```

and

```
(IUndoContext)PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
.getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage()
.getActiveEditor().getEditorInput().getAdapter(IUndoContext.class)
```

which both return null.

So how do I get the UndoContext of the current Java editor?

Answer (score 0):

Some actions in the Java editor use:

```
(IUndoContext)ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getAdapter(IUndoContext.class);
```

However there is another undo context in the text editor source viewer. I can't see a way to access this from outside of the editor.

Comment: No, unfortunately that doesn't help either. Maybe, using operations is the wrong approach to begin with. E.g., the Eclipse refactorings have the sort of Undo behavior that I am looking for. But I guess they use actions rather than operations, right?